# Xcode: How to add Protocol to a socket Connection and send JSON data

Tags: objective-c, json, sockets

I am new to Xcode and I am following [this](https://github.com/zwopple/PocketSocket) github example. And My task is to get connected to a signalling server. The signalling server only accepts connection if protocol is set.

1. Is there a way I can add protocol to the connection. 
   For example:

```html
// create the NSURLRequest that will be sent as the handshake
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"wss://example.com"]];

    // create the socket and assign delegate
    self.socket = [PSWebSocket clientSocketWithRequest:request];
    self.socket.delegate = self;
//Something I need to add

self.socket.addprotocol="Protocol";
```

2> Also I need to send JSON Data to the server below is the Android code that I need write it in Objective C

```js
JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
                message.put("pc", 0);
                message.put("message", "Bye");
                socket.sendText(message.toString());
              
            } catch (JSONException e) {
              }
```

Comment: It's not totally clear to me what you mean by "add a protocol" here. WebSockets *is* a protocol. What's the behavior that you get, and how does it differ from what you expected? To format a JSON message easily, look at [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html).

Comment: something like this:var mySocket = new WebSocket("http://www.example.com/socketserver", "my-custom-protocol"); you can say sub-protocol. My server does not accept anything else then my custom protocol. How do we send JSON text with socket connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question #1, it looks like the PocketSocket library you're using doesn't support sub-protocols, unfortunately. All is not lost, however, because there's a [pull request](https://github.com/zwopple/PocketSocket/pull/16/files) from someone who wanted to add that functionality. You could either merge those changes, or just adapt the single line of code that sets the appropriate outgoing header in the request:

```
[request setValue:[_protocols componentsJoinedByString:@","] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Sec-WebSocket-Protocol"];
```

For question #2, there's [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html), which allows you to easily convert Objective-C NSDictionaries and NSArrays into JSON objects:

```
    NSDictionary *o = @{
                        @"a": @"Ayyyy",
                        @"b": @"Beee"
                        };
    NSError *error;
    NSData *d = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:o options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error JSON-encoding object: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSString *s = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[d bytes]];
        NSLog(@"JSON:\n%@", s);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Mark, I am getting this error. 2016-03-30 16:20:49.856 TestPocketSocket[1889:86291] *** Assertion failure in -
[PSWebSocketDriver writeMessageWithOpCode:data:], /PocketSocket/
PSWebSocketDriver.m:325   2016-03-30 16:20:49.862 TestPocketSocket[1889:86291] *** Terminating app due to
uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: ''
*** First throw call stack:     I followed their sample app

Comment: [request setValue:[@"My-protocol"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Sec-WebSocket-Protocol"];:getting error expected identifier?

Comment: I might get a chance to look at this later, and see if I can get it to work. Have you looked at other WebSocket libraries? Maybe there's one where sub-protocols work without needing any changes?

Comment: I have tried them all: Socket/Rocket(never worked), starscream(worked but not objective C).Can you recommend me something please?Something with MIT license.